# 'this' keyword context inside of a IIFE

Tags: javascript

```js
function foo() {
  console.log(this.a);
}

var a = 2;

(function() {
  "use strict";

  foo(); // 2
})();
```

I was just wondering, how come calling `foo()` still gives the value 2? I thought that since `foo` is called inside of an **IIFE** then `this.a` would evaluate to `undefined`, since there is no `a` variable in the **IIFE**.

Comment: I think because it is declared with `var` on the global scope. a becomes a property of window object.

Comment: Strict mode matters in the location of the function definition, not in the location of the call.

Answer (score 7):

The "use strict" is being applied to the IIFE, not the `foo()` function. As a result, `foo` gets ran in sloppy mode/non-strict mode. Since `foo()` doesn't get an explicit `this` bound to it, it defaults to the global object, which in browsers is the `window`. When you declare `var a` in the global scope, it gets added to the window object as a property, meaning using `this.a` inside of foo will give you the value held in `a`, as it's accessing the `a` property of the `window`.

You would get `undefined` for `this` if foo() was being run in strict mode, not the IIFE:

```js
function foo() {
  "use strict";
  console.log(this); // undefined
  console.log(this.a); // Crash
}

var a = 2;

(function() {
  foo(); 
})();
```

Answer (score 3):

that is because both `foo` and `a` are declared in the global scope that is they are properties of the global object `window`.

the `this` inside IIFE itself will be `undefined` because it is in `strict` mode. but calling `foo` inside the IIFE will make `this` inside the `foo` refer to the `window` object.

and since you already have `a` in `window` it get printed out.

Answer (score 2):

Let's see two things here :-

Firstly your strict mode can apply to `globalThis` when it's declared in that scope, like so :-

```
"use strict";

function foo() {
  console.log(this.a);
}

var a = 2;

(function() {
  foo(); // Throws error since this is undefined
})();
```

Another way could be how @Nick proposed it to run only `foo` in strict mode.

Now secondly,

The `this` inside your IIFE is your `globalThis` which is `window` for browsers. Variables declared with `var` in global scope attach themselves to `window`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function test(){
   return {
      a: 9999,
      testFunc: foo
   }
}
  
function foo() {
  console.log(this)  //this is actually another context which point to its parent.
  console.log(this.a);
}

var a = 2;

(function() {
  "use strict";
  console.log(this) //because of 'use strict', this will lead to undefined
  foo(); // 2
  test().testFunc(); //9999
})();
```